# list.retainAll() on empty list returns true

Tags: java, list

In some experiments, I found out that list.retainAll(list2) returns true if list2 is an empty list even if no changes have been made on the initial list.

Why is that so?

Project code:

```
private static boolean isUpToDate(Map<Long, List<Operation>> writeSet, List<Operation> localWriteSet,
        List<NodeStorage> readSetNode,
        List<RelationshipStorage> readSetRelationship, long snapshotId)
{
    return !writeSet.keySet().stream().filter(id -> id > snapshotId).anyMatch(id -> new ArrayList<>(writeSet.get(id)).retainAll(readSetNode));
}
```

Code it also happened to me:

```
new ArrayList(writeSet.get(id)).retainAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Please show code which reproduces this. See [mcve]

Comment: added code where this happened to me in the project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually read the documentation on [`retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)?

> Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.
>
> **Returns:**
> true if this list changed as a result of the call

Therefore, what you are describing is exactly what you should be seeing:

If you pass an empty list to `list.retainAll()`, all elements will be removed from `list`. Therefore, `list` has been changed and the call will return `true`.

Comment: Ohh I got it the other side around. I thought it removes the ones which are the same. Gotta read better. Sorry

Comment: I should've used removeAll if I don't want it to change.

Comment: To be honest, I ran into the very same confusion a while back, so I don't blame you at all. :)